# How to recover deleted photos from Android's internal memory

Tags: data-recovery

I have Redmi Prime 2 mobile and I accidentally deleted some of my pics and now I have tried as much I can to recover them but I can't recover them. I can recover by using some tools(Mini tool power data recovery my Fav.) but the android device shows only two options i.e MTP and PPT. Mini Tool only works on when I choose USB Storage. I don't know what should I do. Can somebody help me to recover my photos or give a way so that I can connect my Redmi Prime 2 android as USB Storage. I have tried my recovery tools for android but they only shows gallery photos which are not deleted.

Comment: Is the phone rooted?

Comment: Yes, I have rooted android

Answer (score 0):

If fortunately, you have backed up your photographs in Google Photo, then you can simply open it, go to the "Trash" and choose the photos that you've backed up and tap on the "Restore" option.

Note:

1.This method is only useful for the data that have been deleted within 60 days.

2.Be sure that the option "Backup &sync" in the "Settings" of Google Photo has been turned on.
[image]